# Google Analytics API - Website most visited sections

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have generated a specific report in Google Analytics site.

http://www.google.com/analytics

This report makes reference to the most visited content of the site, you can do this by accessing the following section:

Reporting > Behavior > Site Content > All pages

And setting up the metrics to Pageviews

However I've got problems by generating this report through the API. How can I get the same results by making a call to the Google Analytics-API?

In Java should be something like this:

```
private static GaData getResults(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
    // Query the Core Reporting API for the number of page views
    // in the past seven days.
    return analytics.data().ga()
            .get("ga:" + profileId, "7daysAgo", "today", "ga:pageviews")
        .execute();
}
```

But I don't know how to define the desired behavior stated above, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should review the full list of [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) and decide what combination of information you are trying to request. in your case probably the metric [ga:pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pageviews) and the dimension [ga:pagePath](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath). the C[ore reporting developer guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) gives several examples of making requests for dimensions and metrics.

```
analytics.data().ga()
    .get(tableId,                  // Table Id.
        "2012-01-01",              // Start date.
        "2012-01-15",              // End date.
        "ga:pageviews")            // Metrics.
    .setDimensions("ga:pagePath")
    .setMaxResults(25);
```

Here is the specific [Java reference doc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/analytics/v3/java/latest/) to the method you are trying to call.

Comment: That was just what I was looking for. Method Analytics.Data.Ga::get(), was missing the dimensions parameteter. Using The returned class Analytics.Data.Ga.Get was the solution. Thank you very much Matt.